# Sort the array elements based on the elements frequency in java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have written code to sort the array in java based on the frequency of the elements in it. I need better code or pseudo code (without collection framework).Please help with links or code.

```
public class SortByFreq1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[] = { 2, 5, 2, 8, 5, 6, 8, 8, 0, -8 };

        int nArr[] = new int[arr.length];

        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Map<Integer,Integer> sortmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arrList.add(arr[i]);
        }

        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(arrList);

        for (Integer i : set) {  
            map.put(i, Collections.frequency(arrList, i));   
        }

        // System.out.println(map.keySet());
        // sort map by value

        Set<Entry<Integer,Integer>> valList=map.entrySet();
        ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Integer>> tempLst = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(valList);

        Collections.sort(tempLst, new Comparator<Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
                return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });

        int k = 0;

        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : tempLst) {
            int no = entry.getKey();
            int noOfTimes = entry.getValue();

            int i = 0;

            while (i < noOfTimes) {
                nArr[k++] = no;
               i++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nArr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(nArr[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for `(with out collection framework)`?

Comment: Interviewer asked me not to use and also cost of my logic seems to be more.

Comment: ok. You can put all distinct elements in a map and then create a `binary search tree` out of it. Then, do an `inorder` traversal and you are done

Comment: Can you define what could be considered better?

Comment: By "with out collection framework" you mean without `Set` `Map` `List` etc. types or without `Collections` utility class?

Comment: yes not to use Set,Map,list etc because of additional cost for them itself. Or let me put in this way- Need better solution than in the question in terms of performance and memory utilization.

Comment: @Sammetanagasrinivas Solution updated, please check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just curious why couldn't you use the good old bubble sort in the case and just customize a bit the *Bubble* In worst case scenario the time complexity is going to be O(n*n) and space complexity will be O(3n) :)

Pure arrays implementation is going to be something like:

```
private static void bubbleSortByOccurrences(int[] arr) {
    int[][] counter = new int[2][arr.length];
    int counterIndex = -1;

    for (int value : arr) {
        int idx = 0;
        for (; idx <= counterIndex; idx++) {
            if (counter[0][idx] == value) {
                counter[1][idx]++;

                while (idx > 0 && counter[1][idx] > counter[1][idx-1]) {
                    int temp = counter[1][idx];
                    counter[0][idx] = counter[0][idx-1];
                    counter[1][idx] = counter[1][idx-1];
                    counter[0][idx-1] = value;
                    counter[1][idx-1] = temp;
                    idx--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (idx > counterIndex) {
            counter[0][idx] = value;
            counter[1][idx]++;
            counterIndex = idx;
        }
    }

    fillArrayBackwards(arr, counter, counterIndex);
}

private static void fillArrayBackwards(int[] buf, int[][] counter, int counterIndex) {
    for (int i = counterIndex, j = buf.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        for (int k = 0; k < counter[1][i]; k++) {
            buf[j--] = counter[0][i];
        }
    }
}
```

And the same algorithm implemented by using a Bubble class will look something like:

```
private static void bubbleSortByOccurrences(int[] arr) {
    Bubble head = null;

    for (int value : arr) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Bubble(value);
        } else {
            Bubble currentHead = null;
            Bubble current = head;

            for (; current != null && !(current.getValue() == value); current = current.getTail()) {
                currentHead = current;
            }

            if (current == null) {
                current = new Bubble(value);
                current.setTail(head);
                head = current;
            } else {
                current.incrementOccurrences();

                while (current.getTail() != null && current.getOccurrences() > current.getTail().getOccurrences()) {
                    Bubble currentTail = current.getTail();
                    current.setTail(currentTail.getTail());
                    currentTail.setTail(current);

                    if (currentHead != null) {
                        currentHead.setTail(currentTail);
                        currentHead = currentTail;
                    } else {
                        head = currentTail;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fillArrayBackwards(arr, head);
}

private static void fillArrayBackwards(int[] buf, Bubble head) {
    int i = buf.length - 1;
    for (Bubble current = head; current != null; current = current.getTail()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < current.getOccurrences(); j++) {
            buf[i--] = current.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Where the custom defined bubble is as follows:

```
class Bubble {
    private int value;
    private int occurrences;
    private Bubble tail;

    public Bubble(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.occurrences = 1;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getOccurrences() {
        return occurrences;
    }

    public void incrementOccurrences() {
        this.occurrences++;
    }

    public Bubble getTail() {
        return tail;
    }

    public void setTail(Bubble tail) {
        this.tail = tail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind it is quite similar to [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

*ATTENTION*: We are **NOT** to modify the array passed in.

There are two different methods while having almost the same time and space complexity.

- Time complexity: max(n, O(klogk));
- Space complexity: O(n) - the array to be returned;

> k mentioned above is the amount of distinct numbers in the array.

### Built-in Collection Method

Using `Stream` perhaps we can make the process a little bit cleaner though OP is not asking for this:

```
/**
 * 1. count the frequency and sort the entry based on the frequency while using LinkedHashMap to retain the order;
 * 2. fill up the new array based on the frequency while traversing the LinkedHashMap;
 * @param arr
 * @return
 */
private static int[] sortByCounting(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Long> countMap = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldV, newV) -> oldV, LinkedHashMap::new));
    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
        Arrays.fill(newArr, i, i += entry.getValue().intValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

### Custom Method

Since we cannot use *built-in* collection methods, meantime we have to record the count for the number.

Instinctively, we could introduce a **custom pair** to record the `number` and its related `frequency` (or `count` we could say) as our **custom method**.

---

```
private static int[] sortByPlainCounting(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array cannot be empty");
    MyPair[] pairs = prepareMyPairs(arr);
    Arrays.sort(pairs, Comparator.comparing(MyPair::getCount).reversed());
    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (MyPair pair : pairs) {
        Arrays.fill(newArr, i, i += pair.count, pair.key);
    }
    return newArr;
}

static class MyPair {
    int key;
    int count;

    public MyPair(int theKey) {
        this.key = theKey;
        this.count = 1;
    }

    public void inc() {
        this.count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
}

static MyPair[] prepareMyPairs(int[] arr) {
    Integer[] tmpArr = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    Arrays.sort(tmpArr, Comparator.reverseOrder());
    int count = 1;
    int prev = tmpArr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < tmpArr.length; i++) {
        if (tmpArr[i] != prev) {
            prev = tmpArr[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    MyPair[] pairs = new MyPair[count];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++) {
        if (pairs[k] == null) {
            pairs[k] = new MyPair(tmpArr[i]);
        } else {
            if (pairs[k].key == tmpArr[i]) {
                pairs[k].inc();
            } else {
                k++; i--;
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

### A comparison and demonstration

Make a final comparison, we can prove that:

1. average time cost of **custom** is a little bit worse (1.4 times worse) while the worst case is far better (4 times better) than the built-in collection method;
2. the custom method is correct;

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 10_000 + new Random().nextInt(100);
    Long start;
    List<Long> list0 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        int[] arr = RandomGenerator.generateArrays(N, N, N / 10, N / 5, false);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        int[] arr0 = sortByCounting(arr);
        list0.add(System.nanoTime() - start);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        int[] arr1 = sortByPlainCounting(arr);
        list1.add(System.nanoTime() - start);

        System.out.println(isFrequencyEqual(arr0, arr1));
    }
    System.out.println("Collection time cost: " + list0.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(Long::valueOf)));
    System.out.println("Custom   time   cost: " + list1.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(Long::valueOf)));
}


private static boolean isFrequencyEqual(int[] arr0, int[] arr1) {
    Map<Integer, Long> countMap0 = getCountMap(arr0);
    Map<Integer, Long> countMap1 = getCountMap(arr1);
    boolean isEqual = countMap0.entrySet().size() == countMap1.entrySet().size();
    if (!isEqual) return false;
    isEqual = countMap0.values().containsAll(countMap1.values()) &&
            countMap1.values().containsAll(countMap0.values());
    if (!isEqual) return false;
    List<Long> countList0 = countMap0.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Long> countList1 = countMap1.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int i = 0; i < countList0.size(); i++) {
        if (countList1.get(i) != countList0.get(i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static Map<Integer, Long> getCountMap(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldV, newV) -> oldV, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

The helper util method:

```
public static int[] generateArrays(int minSize, int maxSize, int low, int high, boolean isUnique) {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int N = random.nextInt(maxSize - minSize + 1) + minSize;
    if (isUnique) {
        Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
        while (intSet.size() < N) {
            intSet.add(random.nextInt(high - low) + low);
        }
        return intSet.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    } else {
        int[] arr = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

And the test output:

```
Sorted by frequency: true
// ... another 98 same output
Sorted by frequency: true
Collection time cost: LongSummaryStatistics{count=100, sum=273531781, min=466684, average=2735317.810000, max=131741520}
Custom   time   cost: LongSummaryStatistics{count=100, sum=366417748, min=1733417, average=3664177.480000, max=27617114}
```

Comment: The question asks for a solution that doesn't use the collections framework. `Map` is in the collections framework.

Comment: @Sammetanagasrinivas I was kind of confused. But will enclose one to handle that case. By the way, the numbers inside of the array have some ranges? This question can be optimized in several ways, it takes time to implement them all. I will try to add them after my on-hand work.

Comment: @Hearen Like you said, integer ranges plays a very big role here. I presume we will have to settle for a less efficient solution if ranges are completely off. Like `[1,2147483647,1]`

Comment: @vivek_23 updated with the solution solving that situation and also a comparison made for support.

Comment: `java.util.Arrays` is ["a member of the Java Collections Framework."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Yes, you’re right but the major problem here I think is not sorting, so to avoid extra complexity, I was using it here.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in O(n) using pigeonhole sort. Pseudo code:

```
counts = new HashMap<Item, int>(),;
foreach item in elements:
     counts[item] += 1;
buckets = new List<Item>[elements.length+1];
foreach item in counts:
    buckets[counts[item]].Append(item)

for i from 1 to elements.length:
   bucket = buckets[i]; /* edit: looping over i instead over bucket */
   for item in bucket:
      /* edit: if the out has to preserve the original number of elements
               such as [1,5,5,0,1,9,1] will print
               9,0,5,5,1,1,1 instead of 9,0,5,1, then the next line
               has to be repeated i times*/
      System.out.println(item)
```

edit: The same can be written without collection framework, by implementing a hash table and a linked list:

```
class Node {
   public Node next;
   public int value;
};
log2count = Math.ceil(Math.log(elements.length) / Math.log(2));
hashSize = (int) Math.Round(Math.Pow(2, log2count) * 2);

/* countsQuadraticProbing[i] is 0 if the hash entry is empty,
   otherwise it contains the frequency of the element in
   elementsQuadraticProbing[i].
   Note that quadratic probing over a hash table of size 2**k,
   and probing of  (0.5 i + 0.5 i**2) is guaranteed to find an empty
   entry if the hash table is not full.
*/
countsQuadraticProbing = new int[hashSize];
elementsQuadraticProbing = new int[hashSize];
foreach item in elements:
     for i from 0 to hashSize-1:
        index = (item + (i * (i + 1) / 2)) % hashSize;
        if countsQuadraticProbing[index] == 0:
           countsQuadraticProbing[index] = 1;
           elementsQuadraticProbing[index] = item;
           break;
        if elementsQuadraticProbing[index] == item:
           countsQuadraticProbing[index]++;
           break;

buckets = new Node[elements.length+1];
for i from 0 to hashSize-1:
    count = countsQuadraticProbing[index];
    if count != 0:
       Node topNode = new Node();
       topNode.next = buckets[count];
       topNode.value = elementsQuadraticProbing[i];
       buckets[count] = topNode;

/* there are O(N) buckets, total of elements in all buckets O(N),
   overall complexity of the nested loop O(N)
*/
for i from 1 to elements.length:
   node = buckets[i]  /* edit: using i for iteration */
   while node != null:
      /* edit: if the out has to preserve the original number of elements
               such as [1,5,5,0,1,9,1] will print
               9,0,5,5,1,1,1 instead of 9,0,5,1, then the next line
               has to be repeated i times*/
      System.out.println(node.value);
      node = node.next;
```

Comment: one: collection is not allowed as OP required; two: bucket sort is not the ideal choice here - counting is better.

Comment: Counting sort won't work here, since counting sort works on sets of integers, and here there is a map of key value pairs. Regarding containers, I find a hash table trivial to implement, and implementing it here  would have obfuscated the answer.

Comment: We can make hash array for the counting while bucket sort is recursively sorting the bucket and OP's question is about **frequency** from the beginning as you must have known.

Comment: The OP wants to sort the original elements based on their frequency: "sort the array in java based on the frequency of the elements in it". So the question is about the elements and their order, which happens to be based of frequency.

Comment: And bucket sort is not recursive.

Comment: You are quite serious on this, but bucket sort seems using **resusive logic** to ensure the order as wiki points out: Bucket sort, or bin sort, is a sorting algorithm that works by distributing the elements of an array into a number of buckets. Each bucket is then sorted individually, either using a different sorting algorithm, or by **recursively** applying the bucket sorting algorithm. Of course, you can use another sorting after the bucket sorting, but normally we do the recursion to reach the target.

Comment: You are right wrt Wikipedia's bucket sort, which surprises me. In the early 90's, when I learned bucket sort it was a different thing. I'll update the description when I find the algorithm I have known as bucket sort.

Comment: Found it - pigeonhole sort

Comment: How about sorting the array first and then dealing with buckets? This way we won't have to sort each individual bucket

Comment: There is no need to sort buckets in pigeonhole-sort, or pre-sort elements. Such sorting will be O(n log n), where pigeonhole sorting is O(n) in this case.

Comment: Bucket k contains all numbers with frequency k. There is no need to sort these elements further, since we already got what we wanted. This is one of those rare cases when sorting can have an O(n) time complexity.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler You need to mention my name, else SO won't notify me. I feel you need to change  `buckets[counts[item]].Append(counts[item])` to `buckets[counts[item]].Append(item)` in your code. I agree with you with the fact that sorting ain't needed. But I presume storing data this way wouldn't produce anything useful. Let's take `[2, 5, 2, 8, 5, 6, 8, 8, 0, -8]` for example. This would produce `[6,0,-8,2,5,2,5,8,8,8]` whereas `[6,0,-8,2,2,5,5,8,8,8]` makes a bit more sense, meaning sorting elements which collide on frequency is a better data set to work on and I presume OP wants the same.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thanks, good catch on the `Append` issue. Regarding to the list of items, I don't agree that this will be the output. The hash table (***QuadraticProbing) contains each element only once, even if it appears N times. It is possible that the OP would like to repeatedly print the same item according to its count, but I am not sure if it is really so. I'll fix the bug you found, and add a comment regarding to duplicating.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Yes, I agree that it's still unclear how OP wants the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

your solution is better but since am not using any collections it is gonna be huge.

1.sort the list
2. get the frequency of every element 
3. create a new arraylist/ array and store the elements that have higher frequency to lower frequency.

1. sort the list using any sort algorithm
2. get the frequency

   ```
     class CountFrequencies 
   {
    // Function to find counts of all elements present in
    // arr[0..n-1]. The array elements must be range from
    // 1 to n
    void findCounts(int arr[], int n) 
    {
   // Traverse all array elements
   int i = 0;
   while (i < n) 
   {
       // If this element is already processed,
       // then nothing to do
       if (arr[i] <= 0) 
       {
           i++;
           continue;
       }

       // Find index corresponding to this element
       // For example, index for 5 is 4
       int elementIndex = arr[i] - 1;

       // If the elementIndex has an element that is not
       // processed yet, then first store that element
       // to arr[i] so that we don't loose anything.
       if (arr[elementIndex] > 0) 
       {
           arr[i] = arr[elementIndex];

           // After storing arr[elementIndex], change it
           // to store initial count of 'arr[i]'
           arr[elementIndex] = -1;
       } 
       else
       {
           // If this is NOT first occurrence of arr[i],
           // then increment its count.
           arr[elementIndex]--;

           // And initialize arr[i] as 0 means the element
           // 'i+1' is not seen so far
           arr[i] = 0;
           i++;
       }
   }

   System.out.println("Below are counts of all elements");
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       System.out.println(j+1 + "->" + Math.abs(arr[j]));
    }
   ```

above code should give you an output:

```
1 -> 3
2 -> 0
3 -> 2
4 -> 0
5 -> 2
6 -> 0
7 -> 2
8 -> 0
9 -> 2
10 -> 0
11 -> 0
```

3. Now you can easily use the array that stored the frequency of every element to create a new array that contains the most frequent elements in the array
   Note that the list is sorted so that arr[0] is the frequency of 1 arr[1] is the frequency of 2 and so on. Again The code is not efficient as yours it is better to use the collection framework.
   or if you are familiar use binary trees you can add the element into the tree and use inorder traversal !
   Hope you find my answer helpful